# hearing a SoundPool from a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, soundpool

I want to do a listView of buttons with sound.
There is a class called Tile

```
public class Tile extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {
private int voice;
private String name;...}
```

TileAdapter is:

```
public class TileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tile> implements View.OnTouchListener /*implements View.OnTouchListener */{
SoundPool sp;
Context context;
List<Tile> objects;
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tile_layout,parent,false);
    Tile btnTab = (Tile) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTab);
    //Log.d("i want name", btnTab.getName());
    Tile temp = this.getItem(position);
    btnTab.setText(temp.getName());
    createSoundPool();
    sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,1);
    int sound = playSound(temp.getName());
    sp.load(context,sound,1);
    btnTab.setOnTouchListener(this);
    return view;
}
```

}

there is a function that get the name of the tile and return a int eith the sound. the name of the function is "playSound"

there is a function that is need to play the sound.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{
    float f = (float) 0.8;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        if (view instanceof Tile )
        {
            Log.d("lielllll", "asdfghjkl");
            Tile tile = (Tile) view;
            sp.play(playSound(tile.getName()), 1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
        }
        view.setAlpha(1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            view.setAlpha(f);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

when i press a button i cant hear a sound.

Comment: check you set your `Adapter` correctly and you `List` has some data

Comment: @AbuYousuf my list has data because the data is showed on the button

Comment: how you be sure that `getView` not called. If data is showed in button then `getView` must called cause you are creating `Buttons` inside `getView`

Comment: @AbuYousuf you are right. That was my previous problem and I forgot I solved it. This is my current problem

Comment: You should look into some tutorials on using ArrayAdapter. You are ignoring the convertView and inflating a new button every time. This could be related to your issues, but will cause a memory leak if not addressed.